# help to integrate $\int_{1}^{3}(x-1)\ln{x}\mathrm dx$

Tags: integration

can anyone please help to integrate

$$\int_{1}^{3}(x-1)\ln{x}\mathrm dx$$

$u=x-1$

$du=dx$

$dv=\ln{x}$

$v=\int\ln{x}dx$

$$\int_{1}^{3}(x-1)\ln{x}\mathrm dx=(x-1)\int\ln{x}-\int \int\ln{x}dx$$

need help

Comment: It might be better to get rid of the natural log by taking the derivative of that instead.

Comment: is it possible to integrate by letting dv=lnx

Answer (score 1):

You can use the sustitution $x=e^t$
\begin{align*}
\int_1^3(x-1)\ln x\,dx&=\int_0^{\ln3}(e^t-1)te^t\,dt\\
&=\int_1^{\ln 3}(te^{2t}-te^t)\,dt\\
&=\left.\left(\tfrac{t}{2}-\tfrac14\right)e^{2t}-\left(t-1\right)e^t\right|_0^{\ln3}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

The integral can be addressed by parts (integrating $(x-1)$). We can work it out differently by "trying" a few derivatives.

$$(x\log x)'=\log x+\frac xx=\log x+1,$$

$$(x^2\log x)'=2x\log x+\frac{x^2}x=2x\log x+x.$$

Then we can conclude that

$$(x\log x-x)'=\log x,$$

$$\left(\frac{x^2}2\log x-\frac{x^2}4\right)'=x\log x.$$

Answer (score 0):

$\textbf{Hint}$. Try $u=(x-1)\ln x$ and $dv=dx$. Then,

$$\int (x-1)\ln x dx = x(x-1)\ln x-\int x\left(\ln x +1 -\frac{1}{x}\right)dx= x(x-1)\ln x-\int x\ln x dx +\int xdx -\int dx.$$

Now, try for the first integral $w=x\ln x$ and $dy=dx$ and you got it.

Answer (score 0):

Let $I = \int_{1}^{3} (x-1)lnxdx$

Instead set $u = lnx$, $v=\int x-1dx = \frac{x^{2}}{2} -x$

Then $I = \left | (\frac{x^{2}}{2} -x)lnx \right |_{1}^{3} -\int_{1}^{3}\frac{1}{x}(\frac{x^{2}}{2}-x)dx$

$I = \frac{3}{2}ln3 - \int_{1}^{3}\frac{x}{2}-1dx$

$I = \frac{3}{2}ln3 - \left | \frac{x^{2}}{4}-x \right |_{1}^{3}$

$I = \frac{3}{2}ln3 - 0 = \frac{3}{2}ln3$

Answer (score 0):

Recall that

$$\ln(x)=\int_1^x\frac1t\ dt$$

Thus, your integral becomes

$$\int_1^3\int_1^x\frac{x-1}t\ dt\ dx=\int_1^3\int_t^3\frac{x-1}t\ dx\ dt=\int_1^3\frac{3+2t-t^2}{2t}\ dt=\frac32\ln(3)$$